# running python script inside python

Tags: python, bash

I know this question have been asked multiple times, I read multiple questions trying to solve this issue. However, none of those actually worked.

I have a python script I downloaded from: https://github.com/endrebak/kg

I'm trying to run the following command from inside python. It works when I run it directly from the terminal but throws an error when I run it from inside python:

```
/usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes --definition --species=hsa <(echo 01200)
```

using the following code:

```
pathwayID = 01200

cmd="/usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes --definition --species=hsa <(echo {})".format(pathwayID)

tmp = os.popen(cmd).read()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

sh: -c: line 0: `/usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes --definition --species=hsa <(echo 05200)'
```

I tried multiple suggestions, like adding `python` before calling the script

```
cmd="python /usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes --definition --species=hsa <(echo {})".format(pathwayID)
```

Another suggestion was using:

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg', "--mergecol=0","--noheader","--genes","--definition","--species=hsa <(echo '01200')"])
```

This solution was the closest to solving the issue since the actual script is executed. however, it seems that the parameters are not being passed correctly which I don't know why.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run this command with `subprocess`, you need to use a shell that understands the [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) syntax, e.g. `bash`. `/bin/sh`, which is the default shell used by `subprocess`, doesn't support it.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ("/usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes"
       "--definition --species=hsa <(echo {})".format(pathwayID))

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/usr/bin/bash")
out, err = process.communicate()
```

Alternatively, you can save the ID to a temporary file and use input redirection (`<`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

cmd="/usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes --definition --species=hsa <(echo {})".format(pathwayID)

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

The output stream of the command will be piped into in "out" and the error stream will be piped into "err".

Comment: I don't know if this is a viable way to run your program, but you can try: cmd = "echo '%d' | /usr/packages/kg-master/bin/kg --mergecol=0 --noheader --genes --definition --species=hsa" % pathwayID

Comment: Assuming pathwayID is a number, otherwise use %s

Comment: This also did not work, the script is not recognising the parameters